MassTransit service bus not working when deployed to server where two environments both dev and demo are setup in same server
Basically, we are using MassTransit with RabbitMQ in out .Net core application for publishing and consuming messages. We maintain 2 environments - dev and demo in the same server.
For this, we have created 2 virtual hosts dev and demo in RabbitMQ and configured the dev vhost to be used in dev environment and demo vhost to be used in demo environment..
When we run the dev application, the service bus gets started and messages are correctly published and consumed. But in demo, the service bus is not started and the messages are not published or consumed. Need help to figure out a solution for this issue.
Ex. appsettings.json for dev application uses
"RabbitMqSettings": {
 "Uri": "rabbitmq://localhost/dev",
 "UserName": "guest",
 "Password": "guest"
}
a
and for demo it is 

"RabbitMqSettings": {
 "Uri": "rabbitmq://localhost/demo",
 "UserName": "guest",
 "Password": "guest"
}

In the Program.cs we have the configuration like below:
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(mt => mt.AddMassTransit(x => {
    mt.AddConsumer<OrderCreatedConsumer>();
    
    x.UsingRabbitMq((cntxt, cfg) => {
        cfg.Host(uri, c => {
            c.Username(rabbitMqSettings.UserName);
            c.Password(rabbitMqSettings.Password);
        });           
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(cntxt);
    });        
})    
);

In dev logs, we could see below lines:
2024-04-26 13:34:06.9383|0|INFO|MassTransit|Configured endpoint OrderCreated, Consumer: OrderAPI.Services.OrderCreatedConsumer
2024-04-26 13:34:07.2920|0|INFO|MassTransit|Bus started: rabbitmq://localhost/dev

In Demo logs, we could not see Bus Started information.
2024-04-27 13:34:06.9383|0|INFO|MassTransit|Configured endpoint OrderCreated, Consumer: OrderAPI.Services.OrderCreatedConsumer

Not sure why we are not getting the Bus Started information logged for Demo..
Anyone got any idea on this? please help.

You need to give the user access to the virtual host, my guess is that you didn't.
Also, if you configure the host options properly you can set a StartTimeout after which any errors connecting to the broker will be logged.
You should have seen a warning message in the logs if MassTransit was unable to connection, so, check your logs as well.

Thank you for responding.. I have given access for the user to both the virtual host..

Also in logs, I'm not seeing error messages..  Only not seeing the bus started information in the logs for demo.. If I use demo virtual host in dev environment then its working.. But dev virtual host not working when used in demo environment.. Its like, if I try to use MassTransit for both dev and demo, only the dev is working and the other environment is not working..  Both the dev and demo application hosted in same server plays any role here?

I will try host options setup and see if that works.

I tried the following setup with host options  -
builder.Services.AddOptions()
.Configure(options =>
{
options.WaitUntilStarted = true;
});
Its working now.. Thank you so much :)
